# setting return of coroutine into a variable inside another coroutine makes compiler try to convert promise types

Tags: c++, c++20, coroutine

I am currently on an issue where I simply try to co_await coroutine B to save the return of it into a variable inside coroutine A but it tries to convert the promise type of A to the promise type of B.

```
forStackoverflow.cpp: In function ‘myTask<std::optional<int> > getValue(std::vector<int>&, int, bool)’:
forStackoverflow.cpp:68:60: error: cannot convert ‘coroutine_handle<promise_type<std::optional<int>>>’ to ‘coroutine_handle<promise_type<int>>’
   68 |     leaf = co_await suspendableLocateValue(key, array, true);
      |                                                            ^
forStackoverflow.cpp:42:58: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void myTask<T>::await_suspend(std::__n4861::coroutine_handle<myTask<T>::promise_type>) const [with T = int]’
   42 |   void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> coro) const noexcept { coro.promise().boolIsDone = true; }
      |                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <concepts>
#include <coroutine>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct myTask {
  struct promise_type {
    T value_;
    ~promise_type() {}

    myTask<T> get_return_object() {
      return myTask<T> {
        .h_ = std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>::from_promise(*this)
      };
    }

    std::suspend_never initial_suspend() { return {}; }
    std::suspend_always final_suspend() 
    { 
      boolIsDone = true; 
      return {};
    }

    void unhandled_exception() { std::terminate(); }

    std::suspend_always return_value(auto value) {
      value_ = value;
      return {};
    }

    bool boolIsDone = false;
    auto isDone() { return boolIsDone; }
  };

  bool await_ready() const noexcept { return false; }
  void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> coro) const noexcept { coro.promise().boolIsDone = true; }
  void await_resume() const noexcept {}

  std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> h_;
  operator std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>() const { return h_; }
};

myTask<int> suspendableLocateValue(int key, std::vector<int>& array, bool interleave)
{
    int currentInt = 0;
    if (interleave = true)
    {
        //do something here
        co_await std::suspend_always{};
    }
    currentInt = array.at(key);
    co_return currentInt;
}

myTask<std::optional<int>> getValue(std::vector<int>& array, int key, bool interleave)
{
  //int result = array.at(key);
  int leaf;

  if (interleave = true)
  {
    leaf = co_await suspendableLocateValue(key, array, true);
  }

  co_return std::make_optional(leaf);
}

void minimalInterleavedExecution(std::vector<int>& lookup, 
                            std::vector<int>& keys, 
                            std::vector<std::optional<int>>& results,
                            int groupsize)
{
  std::vector<std::coroutine_handle<myTask<std::optional<int>>::promise_type>> handles;

  for (int i = 0; i < groupsize; ++i)
  {
    handles.push_back(getValue(lookup, keys.at(i), true));
  }
  int notDone = groupsize;
  int i = groupsize;
  while (notDone > 0)
  {
    for (int handleIndex = 0; handleIndex < handles.size(); ++handleIndex)
    {
      if (!handles.at(handleIndex).promise().isDone())
      {
        handles.at(handleIndex).resume(); 
      }
      else 
      {
        results.push_back(handles.at(handleIndex).promise().value_);
        if (i < keys.size())
        {
          handles.at(handleIndex) = getValue(lookup, keys.at(i), true);
          ++i;
        }
        else 
        { 
          --notDone; 
          handles.erase(handles.begin() + handleIndex);
          --handleIndex;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> lookup = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100};
  std::vector<int> keys = {4, 2, 0, 6, 9, 0};
  std::vector<std::optional<int>> results;

  minimalInterleavedExecution(lookup, keys, results, 4);
}
```

My original code actually involves a B+Tree and `suspendableLocateValue` is supposed to be a function that finds and returns a leaf of type `myTask<Node>` with a given key and `getValue` is supposed to set the return value of the Node-returning function to a new Node and gets the specific value from the node to return it as an optional.

Comment: This seems to be due to mixing `myTask<std::optional<int>>` and `myTask<int>`. If I change `suspendableLocateValue` to return `myTask<std::optional<int>>` this problem goes away but reveals another. (Compiling with gcc 10.2 and `-fcoroutines -fconcepts-ts -std=c++20`).

Comment: Unrelated: You have assignments in some of your `if` conditions.

Answer (score 1):

In function with return value of `myTask<std::optional<int>>` there is a call

```
leaf = co_await suspendableLocateValue(key, array, true);
```

and `suspendableLocateValue` returns `myTask<int>`. But `await_suspend` is not templated and therefore could not be used:

```
void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> coro) const noexcept
```

So `myTask<U>` could be awaited only in `myTask<U>` coroutines.

When `co_await something` is encountered in the coroutine there are several steps that compiler do to determine what is the meaning of that expression:

1. Is there `await_transform` in enclosing coroutine?
2. Is there `operator co_await`?

Otherwise (your case) it generates code that has `something.await_suspend(h)`, where `h` is a `std::coroutine_handle<P>` and P is a type of an enclosing coroutine's promise.

In your example:

- `something` is `myTask<int>`
- `h` is `std::coroutine_handle<myTask<std::optional<int>>::promise_type>`

so there is a call to `myTask<int>::await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<myTask<std::optional<int>>::promise_type>)` but there is no such function. Compiler tries to convert `std::coroutine_handle<myTask<std::optional<int>>::promise_type>` to actual argument type of `await_suspend` (`std::coroutine_handle<myTask<int>::promise_type>`) and writes an error about it.